# How can I tell what change initiated a workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

If I configure a workflow to start when an item is changed, how can I tell which field changed to initiate the workflow?  What I have in mind is I really only want the workflow to fire if one particular field changes and fall through any other time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title is a bit different than your question so i'll answer what I think is your question with a tutorial article.

http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2007/10/sharepoint-designer-workflows-how-to.html

Comment: Yes, you interpreted my question correctly and this tutorial presents a viable work around.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, you can't.

Workflows don't hold "pre-change" and "post-change" properties like some events do.

The only thing you can do in a workflow is to check if a field value is "==" or "!=" to a value.

Some possible workarounds:

1. What you can do is [write a event reciever](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx) to catch the list item updating event and then act on the data. [James Love](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/549/james-love) explained this in a great answer to "[How can I detect whether a specific column changed in an SPItemEventReceiver.ItemUpdated event (SP 2010)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-specific-column-changed-in-an-spitemeventreceiver-item)".
2. You can add a "hidden" field to the list that gets updated by the workflow when the list changes.  This would hold the "old" value.  Not practical, but simpler to implement than an event receiver.